# How to Map One directional Relationship with different key

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I like to map relationship from TypeOne to Items.
Idea is that I want to make the Items to be available for any type by their Type's GUID.
Does EF support this kind of relation and how can I map the relationship to include Items in TypeOne.

** TypeOne **

```
+-------+--------+--------+
|  id   |  name  |  GUID  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  1    |   one  | 11111  |
|  2    |   two  | 22222  |
|  3    |  three | 33333  |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

** TypeTwo **

```
+-------+--------+--------+
|  id   |  name  |  GUID  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  1    |   one  | 44444  |
|  2    |   two  | 55555  |
|  3    |  three | 66666  |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

** Items **

```
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
|  id   |  name  |  type    | TypeGUID  |
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
|  1    |   one  |  TypeOne |   11111   |
|  2    |   two  |  TypeTwo |   44444   |
|  3    |  three |  TypeTwo |   66666   |
+-------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

TypeOne.cs

```
public class TypeOne{
[Key]
public int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
public GUID guid {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Items> items {get;set;}
}
```

Context.cs

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<TypeOne>.ToTable("TypeOne","TypeOne");
ModelBuilder.Entity<TypeOne>.HasKey(x=>x.id).Property(x=>x.TypeOneid);
***ModelBuilder.Entity<TypeOne>(x=>x.items).WithMany<Item>().Map(m=>{m.MapLeftKey("GUID");m.MapRightKey("TypeGUID");});***
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeOne>().HasMany(e => e.Items).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(e => e.TypeGUID);
```

...or...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeOne>().HasMany(e => e.Items).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(e => e.TypeGUID);
```

As is probably self explanatory, the first line of code sets up the relationship so that the relationship between an Item and TypeOne is required (read, an instance of Item cannot exist without an instance of TypeOne).  The second line of code sets up this relationship as optional.  I am assuming the former since a GUID is a non-nullable type.